# File upload with Django form

Tags: django

I am trying to upload video files to vimeo, this is my code
views.py

```
def upload_to_vimeo(request):
    token = 'xxxxx'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video_file = request.POST.get("video_file")
        v = vimeo.VimeoClient(
            token=token,
        )
        video_uri = v.upload(video_file)
        print(video_uri)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'forms/video_upload_form.html', {})
```

template

```
                <form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="file">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload">
                </form>
```

but it throws error

```
AttributeError at /upload_to_vimeo/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

but I can directly upload without a form as follows

```
 v = vimeo.VimeoClient(
        token=token,
    )
    video_uri = v.upload('client_admin/test1.mp4')
```

How I can do it with a form, any help

**Edit**

```
Traceback:

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py" in __get_file_size
  193.             return os.path.getsize(filename)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py" in getsize
  50.     return os.stat(filename).st_size

During handling of the above exception (stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType), another exception occurred:

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/biju/Documents/mtenant/client_admin/views.py" in upload_to_vimeo
  773.         video_uri = v.upload(video_file)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py" in upload
  43.         filesize = self.__get_file_size(filename)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py" in __get_file_size
  195.             return len(filename.read())

Exception Type: AttributeError at /upload_to_vimeo/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

This is the error traceback  and urls file is as follows

```
path('upload_to_vimeo/', upload_to_vimeo, name='upload_to_vimeo'),
```

Comment: You'll get file in `request.FILES` not in `request.POST`.

Comment: I have changed to files as you said, but the error is same

Comment: @Biju, I guess that the user isn't uploading the file. Check my answer, and be sure to read through the docs for `request.FILES`

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` and the complete traceback?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen, i have edited the question to include traceback and url

Comment: Did you try changing the form action as specified in my answer?

Comment: yes change the action to empty string

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things wrong with your code. Do all of the following, and check whether it works

**Views**

- You aren't doing validation, so if the `video_file` is `None`, the error you keep saying will come
- You should get the file from `request.FILES`

```py
def upload_to_vimeo(request):
    token = 'xxxxx'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video_file = request.FILES.get("video_file") # Returns None if there is no file
        if not video_file: # If the user hasn't uploaded the file, 
            return redirect('some-error-page') # redirect to some error page or to the same page with an error message. Or do something else
        v = vimeo.VimeoClient(
            token=token,
        )
        video_uri = v.upload(video_file)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'forms/video_upload_form.html', {})
```

**HTML**

- You aren't setting the name attribute to the file.
- I'm not sure about this, but I don't think you are supposed to put a dot in the `action` attribute (correct me in the comments if I'm wrong). Setting the `action` attribute to a blank string will POST it to the same page.

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="video_file">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, even if i change to request.files the error is same, my doubt is it actually a post request?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're omitting the name attribute for your `file` input field,
hence `request.POST.get("video_file")` returns none.

Add `name` to your file input field `name="video_file"`

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="video_file">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload">
</form>
```

UPDATE

update your `view`

`video_file = request.FILES['video_file']`

Comment: @crazychukz, it is a valid point, but still the error is there,  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @Biju I have updated the answer. It should get the file now. I tested locally myself

Comment: now it throws another error Exception Type: AttributeError at /upload_to_vimeo/ Exception Value: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: @Biju from the code you've so far I can't see what could be causing this new error... I can't see any reference to the `message` variable or where you tried accessing it

Comment: Thank you guys, I have got answer from this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999871/attributeerror-at-upload-to-vimeo-typeerror-object-has-no-attribute-message